# Sort polars DataFrame using column with text and numericals

Tags: python-polars

If I have a DataFrame like

```
┌────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ Name   ┆ Value                │
│ ---    ┆ ---                  │
│ str    ┆ list[str]            │
╞════════╪══════════════════════╡
│ No. 1  ┆ ["None", "!!!"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ No. 10 ┆ ["0.3", "OK"]        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ No. 2  ┆ ["1.1", "OK"]        │
```

How can I sort it by numerical value.
Ie I want to pull the string from the Name column and extract only the numerical elements when sorting.

Ie

```
┌────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ Name   ┆ Value                │
│ ---    ┆ ---                  │
│ str    ┆ list[str]            │
╞════════╪══════════════════════╡
│ No. 1  ┆ ["None", "!!!"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ No. 2  ┆ ["1.1", "OK"]        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ No. 10 ┆ ["0.3", "OK"]        │
```

Can't see the polars expression needed and not sure you can pass a custom python function.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can to use [str.extract](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.str.extract.html#polars.Series.str.extract) to get the number from the string, using a regular expression.

Then cast it to int and sort:

```py
pl.DataFrame({"Name": ["No. 1", "No. 12", "No. 2"]}).sort(
    pl.col("Name").str.extract(r"No\. ([0-9]*)", 1).cast(int)
)
```

Comment: I needed a non strict cast
df.sort(pl.col("Site").str.extract(r".*([0-9]*)", 1).cast(int, strict=False))

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you want to sort by numbers in `List`:

```py
df.sort(
    pl.col("Value").arr.get(0).cast(pl.Float32, strict=False),
    nulls_last=False
)
```